# JSONP Query and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, callback, jsonp

I am trying to iterate through an array of usernames and add the resulting JSONP requests to an array that can be displayed using AngularJS. As follows:

**HTML SECTION**

```
<div id = "displayUL" ng-controller="userController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in results">{{user.user}}<img ng-src="{{user.logo}}">{{user.etcetera}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT SECTION**

```
        var app = angular.module('userAPI', []);

        app.controller('userController', function($scope,$http){
        //Our user name array
        $scope.inputUsers= ["userA", "userB", "userC"];
        $scope.results = [];
        //Loop through each user
        $.each($scope.inputUsers,function(key,value){
            var currentUserData = {};
            currentUserData.user = value;

            //URL Request - defined elsewhere with callback for JSONP
            var currentURL = streamURL + value + callbackPostfix;

           $.getJSON(currentURL, function(data){
                //Update temp obj with current data results
                currentUserData.found = data.found
                currentUserData.logo = data.logo;
                ...
                currentUserData.ecetera = data.ecetera;
                //Update results array with current data obj
                $scope.results.push(currentUserData);
           });
         });
```

When this runs, the results array is empty.  Does the JSONP callback fire before the Angular has a chance to update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the url and response are correct, your problem is using `$.getJSON` which isn't part of angular.

Whenever you make changes to the scope with code that is outside of angular core you need to tell angular to run a digest to update view with scope changes using `$scope.$apply()`.

I would suggest you convert to using `$http.jsonp` instead which will handle digests internally.

```
      $.getJSON(currentURL, function(data){
            //Update temp obj with current data results
            currentUserData.found = data.found
            currentUserData.logo = data.logo;
            ...
            currentUserData.ecetera = data.ecetera;
            //Update results array with current data obj
            $scope.results.push(currentUserData);
            // now time for a digest to update view
            $scope.$apply();
       });
```

Comment: That works. Tried with the $http.jsonp but I got the XML Cross-Origin policy error which is why I'm using $.getJSON because the site has JSONP Callback allowance.

Comment: just means you aren't using `$http.jsonp` properly